# Python simple web server

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to to print some simple variables using the built in HTTP server in Python

```
class WebServer:
    def __init__(self):
        from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
        import urlparse
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), self.do_GET)
        server.serve_forever()

    def do_GET(self):
        parsed_path = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
        message_parts = [
                'CLIENT VALUES:',
                'client_address=%s (%s)' % (self.client_address, self.address_string()),
                'command=%s' % self.command,
                'path=%s' % self.path,
                'real path=%s' % parsed_path.path,
                'query=%s' % parsed_path.query,
                'request_version=%s' % self.request_version,
                '',
                'SERVER VALUES:',
                'server_version=%s' % self.server_version,
                'sys_version=%s' % self.sys_version,
                'protocol_version=%s' % self.protocol_version,
                '',
                'HEADERS RECEIVED:',
                ]
        for name, value in sorted(self.headers.items()):
            message_parts.append('%s=%s' % (name, value.rstrip()))
        message_parts.append('')
        message = '\r\n'.join(message_parts)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(message)
        return
```

But i seem to get this error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.0.1.3', 52251)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: do_GET() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
----------------------------------------
```

def do_GET(self): seems to be receiving more then just self, what am i missing?

Comment: Don't you need a `HandlerClass`?

Comment: isn't that self.do_GET in this case?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the module you're using :) you're passing in a function when a fully fledged object is expected http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Comment: you could sublcass it and implement do_GET like in this example http://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit `WebServer` from a Request Handler like this:

```
class WebServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
```

You will probably have to change your imports for that.

Then pass it as an argument to `HTTPServer` like this:

```
server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), WebServer)
```

Comment: It works for me if I move `server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), WebServer)
server.serve_forever()` after the definition of `WebServer`.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in a function, when a `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` is expected. In other words, Python is trying to instantiate your object using a `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` `__init__` method, but you've provided a function that takes a different amount of arguments.

Instead of passing a plain function, sublcass `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. The example linked by @dm03514 in the comments will get you started.